# How do I pass a key to a function in ESNext?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ecmascript-next, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm writing a gutenberg block plugin for WordPress, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the new ESNext syntax. I have a list of fields with a key:value pairing. Here is the code that I have which is working:

```
{
  ...
  edit: function( { className, attributes, setAttributes } ) {
    return (
      <div className={ className }>
        <label className="field">
          <span className="field__label">Name</span>
          <PlainText
            className="field__input"
            id="email"
            value={ attributes.name }
            onChange={ ( name ) => setAttributes( { name } ) }
          />
        </label>
        <label className="field">
          <span className="field__label">Email</span>
          <PlainText
            className="field__input"
            id="email"
            value={ attributes.email }
            onChange={ ( email ) => setAttributes( { email } ) }
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

I would like this code to be less repetitive and avoid the copy-paste. This is how far I got:

```
{
  edit: function( { className, attributes, setAttributes } ) {
    var fields = {
      name:    'Name',
      email:   'Email',
      phone:   'Phone',
      website: 'Website',
    }
    var html = [];
    for ( var field_key in fields ) {
      var label = fields[ field_key ];
      html.push( (
        <label className="field" key={field_key}>
          <span className="field__label">{ label }</span>
          <PlainText
            className="field__input"
            id={field_key}
            value={ attributes[field_key] }
            onChange={ ( ??? ) => setAttributes( { ??? } ) }
          />
        </label>
      ) );
    }
    return (
      <div className={ className }>
        {html}
      </div>
    );
  },
}
```

How do I pass the `field_key` variable into the `setAttributes` function?

Comment: Try `onChange={( name ) => setAttributes({ [name]: attributes[name] })}`

Comment: @dfsq It didn't work. I also tried your code, but with `field_key` instead of `name`, that didn't work either.

Comment: Mistake. It should be `onChange={( name ) => setAttributes({ [name]: fields[name] })}`.

Comment: Almost, but not quite. I got it working with this: `onChange={( v ) => setAttributes({ [field_key]: v })}`, but now I have the problem that it's only updating the last field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need the `handler` function to bind `field_key`. If you just pass an arrow function to `onChange` it will bind `field_key` and you can then pass it to `setAttributes`:

```
for (const field_key in fields) {
  const label = fields[field_key];

  html.push(
    <label className="field" key={field_key}>
      <span className="field__label">{ label }</span>
      <PlainText
        className="field__input"
        id={field_key}
        value={ attributes[field_key] }
        onChange={() => { setAttributes({ [field_key]: fields[field_key] }); }}
       />
    </label>
  ); 
}
```

I put an example up on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBQExa?editors=0010) to illustrate this (React example but should work in your case as well).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. By the time `onChange` is triggered the `for loop` has completed and `field_key` references the last key, "website". To solve this I created a closure for the handler function that locks the reference to `field_key` inside the current iteration.

```
const handler = (setter, key) => value => setter( { [key]: value } );
{
  ...
  edit: function( { className, attributes, setAttributes } ) {
    let fields = {
      name:    'Name',
      email:   'Email',
      phone:   'Phone',
      website: 'Website',
    }
    let html = [];
    for ( let field_key in fields ) {
      let label = fields[ field_key ];
      html.push( (
        <label className="field" key={field_key}>
          <span className="field__label">{ label }</span>
          <PlainText
            className="field__input"
            id={field_key}
            value={ attributes[field_key] }
            onChange={handler( setAttributes, field_key )}
          />
        </label>
      ) );
    }
    return (
      <div className={ className }>
        {html}
      </div>
    );
  },
  ...
}
```